# Can a MongoDB replace a mysql database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

If I will create a WordPress blog that uses mysql, can I use MongoDB instead of mysql?

Comment: You will have more luck with your question if you put more effort into it and show that you're a professional and have made an effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: This doesn't seem even remotely reasonable.  MongoDB and MySQL serve completely different purposes and operate completely differently.  They are not even close to the same.  Also, one really does wonder what your motivation is for doing this... because one is cool right now or something?  Never do that.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need for wordpress to be able to use MongoDB natively as a backend - MongoDB is not a drop-in replacement for a relational database.

It looks like there's some kind of fork to add that support?  See here: http://www.mongopress.org/